# Emacs org: Promote all headings of a subtree during export?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use emacs org a lot to export parts of org documents to latex/pdf. I was wondering whether there is a way to promote all headings of the selected parts during the export process. For instance, suppose the file looks like this:

```
* Project 1
** Task 1                   :export:
*** Introduction
    Text text text. 
*** Results
    Text text text. 
* Project 2
```

The emacs org export to latex would produce a tex file of the following structure:

```
\section{Project 1}
\subsection{Task 1}
\subsubsection{Introduction}
    Text text text. 
\subsubsection{Results}
    Text text text.
```

But because there is not highest level in the part to be exported, it would make more sense to have the following structure:

```
\section{Task 1}
\subsection{Introduction}
    Text text text. 
\subsection{Results}
    Text text text.
```

Or, even better:

```
\title{Task 1}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
    Text text text. 
\section{Results}
    Text text text.
```

I was wondering whether anyone has an idea how to go about this? My lisp skills are unfortunately very rudimentary, seems like it should not be too hard.

Thanks!

Stephan

Comment: I would have added a comment, but unfortunately I dont have enough reputation.
Here's a very nice tutorial, that should fit your needs. [emacs org lisp tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html)

Comment: Moreover, try to post your question there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user3321294 Be aware that the tutorial mentioned in this answer is for `org-mode` versions older than 8.0, and `org-mode` "has transitioned to a [new export framework](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/ox-overview.html)".

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. When I export your example input file to `.tex` the resulting file contains `Project 1` as a top-level `\section`: `\section{Project 1}`. What version of `org-mode` are you using? I am on version 8.2.6. What did you do to prevent `org` from including `Project 1` in the output file?

Comment: You are correct -- I updated the example to correct that error. Does it now look like what you get? I am using org-mode 8.2.5.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for clarifying. Please see my answer below for my take on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first behavior you describe can be achieved by adding the following to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
;; Define a function for turning a single subtree into a top-level tree
;; (:export: headings might be located at an arbitrary nesting level,
;; so a single call to "org-promote-subtree" is not enough):
(defun org-promote-to-top-level ()
  "Promote a single subtree to top-level."
  (let ((cur-level (org-current-level)))
    (loop repeat (/ (- cur-level 1) (org-level-increment))
          do (org-promote-subtree))))

;; Define a function that applies "org-promote-to-top-level" 
;; to each :export: subtree:
(defun org-export-trees-to-top-level (backend)
  "Promote all subtrees tagged :export: to top-level.
BACKEND is the export back-end being used, as a symbol."
  (org-map-entries 'org-promote-to-top-level "+export"))

;; Make org-mode run "org-export-subtrees-to-top-level" as part of the export
;; process:
(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'org-export-trees-to-top-level)
```

Implementing the second behavior is a bit trickier but you can use the`org-export-trees-to-top-level` function as a starting point if that's what you ultimately need. I'd like to point out, however, that this will not work for files with more than one `:export:` subtree (unless you also come up with a way to decide which headline would become the `\title` in these cases).

---

#### Sources:

- Logic of `org-promote-to-top-level` based on source code of `org-cycle-level` command
- [Using the `org-mode` mapping API](http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-mapping-API.html)
- [Relevant information about export hooks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html)